# Links not working in ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I am using ng-bind-html but the links in the to binding html won't work.

This is the code for binding the content:

```
<div class="list-group-item-text" ng-class="article.img.length >0 ? 'col-md-10' : 'col-md-12'"
                 ng-bind-html="article.content | to_trusted">
</div>
```

This is how the link gets compiled 
[image: Compiled link]

the to_trusted filter looks like this:

```
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
}])
```

and still, when I click on the link nothing happens. Nothing in the console neither.

Ideas?

Edit: The input string:

```
It was never really finished and is actually in a state which is a result of playing around with jQuery and other tools. <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Edit2: I should say, the link works completely fine if I right-click it and then click "open in a new tab"

Comment: Can you show the string that you put into `article.content`? Specifically the `<a>` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually quite easy and embarassing.

I had an `<a> </a>` wrapped around the container where the ng-bind-html got rendered. Changed it to a div. Obviously everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

How I use it, is I use a compile directive that takes the desired string content, inserts it to the elements and compiles it. It has a high priority of 1000 (default for directives is 0), which means it works before the `ng-bind-html` directive (higher number -> takes precedence), and then when the `ng-bind-html` directive runs, it knows that the links are links:

```
    <div 
         compile-html="text" 
         ng-bind-html="text | to_trusted"></div>
    </div>
```

The Compile Directive:

```
var CompileHtmlDirective = (function () {
    function CompileHtmlDirective($compile) {
        this.$compile = $compile;
        this.priority = 1000;
        this.link = function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.compileHtml, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    element.html(newVal);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        };
    }

    return CompileHtmlDirective;
})();
```

[Here it is in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11565/)

Comment: Using this, the link is shown as plain text, not even handled as a link.

Comment: @Benedikt Take a look now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this, but this is still not working... I think the link is compiled correctly, there is just something from angular that overwrites the browsers click functionality and results into nothing happening...

Comment: Hey @OmriAharon. Thanks for posting this. It resolved exactly what I was looking for. How were you able to find these features for Angular? I'm not sure I would've been able to solve this myself so I'm wondering what led you to this solution.